# Eulerian graph has no bridges

Tags: graph-theory

my problem is to prove that Eulerian graph has no bridges. Can please anyone help me with that? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

A graph is eulerian iff it has a Eulerian circuit. If you remove an edge, what was once a Eulerian circuit becomes a Eulerian path, so if the graph was connected, it stays connected.

Answer (score 0):

An eulerian Graph has a eulerian circuit (for example by Hierholzers algorithm) that visits each vertex twice and doesn't use the same edge twice.

Thus there are at least two edge-disjoint paths between any pair of vertices.